# How to fix not working ⌘ ⎋ shortcut in Lion 10.7

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a new MacBook Pro 15" early 2011 and use Lion.

1. For "Launchpad" I can't use the Shortcut F1.
2. For "Move focus to menu bar" I can't use the Shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⎋</kbd>).

Simply said, there are functions, which are not working with one specific Shortcut. I can assign it, but it does not work.

The Shortcuts works for all the other functions and the one function works with all the other Shortcuts.

Sometimes when I wildly clicked around and restarted, the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⎋</kbd>) worked with "Move focus to menu bar" one time.

What could I do to fix the bug?

Comment: I can replicate this bug with my iMac mid-2010. It works when set to ctrl+esc (or any other shortcut), but not cmd+esc. I can use cmd+esc for any other function, but not for this one.

Comment: There are some bugs where the menu bar doesn't get shortcuts when an app is in full screen. Are your troubles happening when the display isn't in full screen mode?

Comment: The problem occurs in full screen as well as in normal window mode. The weird thing is: The Shortcut cmd+esc (⌘+⎋) works for the menu bar, IF I activated the menu bar with the Shortcut for MOVE FOCUS TO STATUS MENUS (also here the same in full screen or window mode) right before and a menu icon on the right side of the menu bar is highlighted

Comment: I've also encountered problems with assigning ⌘+⎋ as a shortcut or as a hotkey within an application in Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mountain lion the bug seems to be fixed.
Now I have no problem assigning the hotkeys as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> and assign and enable the shortcuts you want.

Comment: Your answer works for many shortcuts, but there's something strange about ⌘+⎋ in Lion.

Comment: Yes. ⌘+⎋ doesn't work with all functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've realized that the ctrl-Fn shortcuts only work if I tick the option to use the function keys as "normal function keys".
This option is in Systems Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard. 
I believe it is unticked by default (ie the Fn keys work as shortcuts for brightness, sound level, and music playing). Once ticked, Ctrl-F2 works like a charm. Alternatively, you can leave this option unchecked and instead hit CTRL+fn+F2 and the intended function will work fine.

Comment: Yes but F1 is F1 not the "lesser brightness" key. So I used F1, when the same key reduces your brightness then you have to hold down the fn key. The problem didn't go away ;(